# Usage of word "meat"

Tags: meaning, nouns

I am not a native English speaker and never lived in an English-speaking country, so I wonder how you would apply this word.

Would you apply the term "meat" to the following things?

1. Muscle tissue of a cow
2. Liver tissue of a cow
3. Brain tissue of a cow
4. Muscle tissue of other beasts (swine, goat, rabbit)
5. Muscle tissue of a bird (chicken, quail, turkey)
6. Muscle tissue of a fish
7. Muscle tissue of mollusks, such as oyster, squid, shellfish, snail
8. Tissue of polyp, medusa
9. Tissue of a sponge
10. Tissue of a mushroom
11. Tissue of a plant

Comment: And, sweetmeats, meat from flour, meaty roles in movies, more.

Answer (score 5):

It may seem rather odd, but you could apply "meat" to all of the above.  Probably.

Wiktionary [defines meat thus:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meat)

> 4. *(uncountable)* The flesh of an animal used as food.
>
> 5. *(uncountable)* Any relatively thick, solid part of a fruit, nut etc.

The first of these includes your points 1-7 fairly straightforwardly.  Some vegetarians would quibble about whether fish was meat or not, but they are really drawing a separate(valid) distinction between fish and mammals.

By the time we're talking about polyps and sponges, most people wouldn't normally think of them in terms of eating.  You could call them meat, but we usually don't.

Mushrooms and plants bring us to the second definition.  If the mushroom or plant is substantial ("meaty"), we do sometimes refer to it as meat.  It would usually be qualified in some way to make it clear that we weren't referring to animal meat, but the concept is well understood.  It's moderately commonly used with reference to nuts and some fruit, rather less commonly with other plant or fungal matter.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), markdown does not currently support starting ordered lists at an arbitrary number. There are some workarounds, like using &nbsp; to get similar spacing.

Comment: What about kaviar?

Comment: Caviar and other eggs don't really fit either definition.  I haven't heard anyone describe them as meat, either.  (@Mitch: there are too many markup languages!)

Answer (score 2):

So, this is actually a really good question, because exactly what counts as meat can vary a bit from person to person or situation to situation.  For example, some people consider themselves vegetarians while still eating fish.  Others say that no fish is allowed.  So my best breakdown (open to comments):

**Always meat**:

- Muscle tissue of a cow
- Liver tissue of a cow
- Muscle tissue of other beasts (swine, goat, rabbit)
- Muscle tissue of a bird (chicken, quail, turkey)

**Maybe meat**:

- Muscle tissue of a fish
- Muscle tissue of mollusks, such as oyster, squid, shellfish, snail
- Brain tissue of a cow (I suppose if eaten, it could be considered meat, but I'm not familiar with brain eating.

**Never meat**

- Tissue of a sponge
- Tissue of a mushroom
- Tissue of a plant
- Tissue of polyp, medusa (unless these have something more akin to muscle than I'm thinking)

*Edit: I'll also point out that `meat` can be used to describe the edible or substantial part of anything, e.g. `the meat of the issue` or `he cracked the nut to get at its meat`, but I assume that's not the sort you're referring to above*

Comment: crab meat appears in Wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_meat Snail meat and clam meat also appear in google searches.

Comment: @John Satta - right, which is why I put them in the maybe section.  They're certainly animal flesh, but under certain definitions of `meat`, fish, shellfish, etc. are excluded.

Comment: @Dusty - Sorry, I missed the "Maybe Meat" heading - that's what I get for skimming.

Comment: @John Satta - no worries.  I toyed with *sometimes meat* but couldn't come up with something that really nailed what I was going for.

Comment: I was rather surprised to see plants on OP's list at all. Perhaps there's some confusion because of *flesh*, which can refer to animals as well as to fruits and vegetables.

Comment: If you're going to allow dietary definitions of meat into the discussion, I would say birds do not meet the standard of "always" meat.  If there were a "usually" or "probably" category, I might put them in there, but as things stand, "maybe" is the most accurate category for bird flesh.

Answer (score 2):

"Meat", unqualified, always refers to [tetrapods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tetrapod) (i.e. mammals, birds, reptiles, probably amphibians), as opposed to fish, arthropods or molluscs.

But with suitable qualification you can use "meat" to refer to any animal flesh: "crab meat" is common, as John Satta points out; and while I would not expect to see "tuna meat", I would not find it odd for somebody to refer to "separating the meat from the bone" when referring to tuna. (We do have "tuna steaks").

The use of "meat" for plant (or fungus) material, or for food in general, I would regard as archaic.

*(Edited to generalise 'mammals' to 'tetrapods')*

Comment: What about birds?

Comment: True. I've replaced 'mammals' by 'tetrapods'.

Comment: Are all birds tetrapods?

Comment: Yes, by definition. This is the classificatory "tetrapod", meaning the clade that contains those classes irrespective of the number of legs that any given species may have. Whales and snakes are tetrapods, because they are respectively mammals and reptiles, even though neither has four legs.